# How to make the title of a file to expand the whole line in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

In my exam, I really want the title to expand the whole top line of the page instead of centered like this:

[image]

I wonder if there is any way to change it. My .Rmd file is attached for reference.

thanks a lot!

```
---
title: 'Fall 2022    \ \ SOCI 710  \  \ Exam1 \  \ Name:'
author: "10/25/2022"
date: ' '
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
geometry: margin=.5in  
---

\vspace{-1cm}
- total of 100 pts.
- Read all questions carefully. Give a complete answer to each question, and show all work. Partial credit for partially correct answers can only be given when work is shown.

## 1 (total 12 points, 3pts for each part)

The Current Employment Statistics (CES) is a survey of employers by the U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics. The following figure lists in alphabetical order a population of 20 employers eligible for the CES:



- For a sample from the population, you could just list the numbers of record; for example, {1,2,3} means we sample first three elements out of the population. 

a.  Give an example of simple random sample of size 3.
\vspace{1in}
b.  Give an example of systematic sample of size 3. 
\vspace{1in}
c.  Give an example of stratified sample of size 3, with `Group` as the stratification variable.
\vspace{1in}
d.  Give an example of cluster sample of size 3, with `Group` as the cluster variable.
\vspace{1in}

## 2. (total 24 points)

The top management of a large corporation wants to estimate $t$, the total meals expenses for 2550 employees on their 300 project teams.  They took a simple random sample of 50 teams and added up the meals expenses for all members of each selected team. Note that $y_i$ = total meals expenses for the $i^{th}$ team.

|Sample Statistics  |   Mean    |   Standard Deviation |
|--------|----|----|
|Meals Expenses per team        |$\$829$        |$\$140$|
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or specify the desired output

Comment: thanks for your help: is that possible to make the title  start at the very left end of the top line? You know, we could easily do it in word like this: Fall 2022                  SOCI 710         Exam1           Name:

Comment: or like effect  of "add header" in word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LaTeX package [`titling`](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf) has specific options to do this. There even a example to solve your case. See section 2.1.1, page 2 of the package docs.

**header.tex**

```
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\sffamily}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}
```

```
---
title: 'Fall 2022    \ \ SOCI 710  \  \ Exam1 \  \ Name:'
author: "10/25/2022"
date: ' '
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
geometry: margin=.5in  
---

\vspace{-1cm}
- total of 100 pts.
- Read all questions carefully. Give a complete answer to each question, and show all work. Partial credit for partially correct answers can only be given when work is shown.

## 1 (total 12 points, 3pts for each part)

The Current Employment Statistics (CES) is a survey of employers by the U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics. The following figure lists in alphabetical order a population of 20 employers eligible for the CES:



- For a sample from the population, you could just list the numbers of record; for example, {1,2,3} means we sample first three elements out of the population. 

a.  Give an example of simple random sample of size 3.
\vspace{1in}
b.  Give an example of systematic sample of size 3. 
\vspace{1in}
c.  Give an example of stratified sample of size 3, with `Group` as the stratification variable.
\vspace{1in}
d.  Give an example of cluster sample of size 3, with `Group` as the cluster variable.
\vspace{1in}

## 2. (total 24 points)

The top management of a large corporation wants to estimate $t$, the total meals expenses for 2550 employees on their 300 project teams.  They took a simple random sample of 50 teams and added up the meals expenses for all members of each selected team. Note that $y_i$ = total meals expenses for the $i^{th}$ team.

|Sample Statistics  |   Mean    |   Standard Deviation |
|--------|----|----|
|Meals Expenses per team        |$\$829$        |$\$140$|
```

---

[image]

---

If you want to make similar changes to author or date there are `\preauthor`, `\postauthor`, `\predate`, `\postdate` options too.

Comment: It works-thank you very much! Can I ask you another question:  I wonder if there is any way to adjust the space between the four terms:  Fall 2022    \ \ SOCI 710  \  \ Exam1 \  \ Name: It would be much better if there is a bigger distance among those four terms.